# Setting empty string on window object

Tags: javascript

Are there any drawbacks to specifying an empty string in the window as a property?

For example:

```
window[""] = function() {
    console.log("foo");
}

(); // will log foo
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RL33q/).

Edit: of course, this would break putting stuff inside parens for clarification. You'd probably want this instead:

```
window[""] = function(prop) {
    console.log(prop);
    return prop;
}
```

Further edit: The above code is an IIFE of sorts. Oops. This is why I don't like automatic semicolon insertion:

```
window[""] = function() {
    console.log("foo");
}();
```

Comment: For what possible reason would you *want* to?

Comment: Imagine if jQuery didn't require the `$`! Shorter code.

Comment: How would it be shorter? You couldn't call that variable without using bracket notation, could you?

Comment: As clarified by Rocket, no, I couldn't. This is why I don't like semicolon insertion...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is *not* running as you think it is.

```
();
```

This is actually a syntax error on its own.

Try this and see:

```
window[""] = function() {
    console.log("foo");
};

();
```

Your code is actually being interpreted as (the white space is ignored between the `}` and `()`):

```
window[""] = function() {
    console.log("foo");
}();
```

Which runs the anonymous function and set its return value (`undefined`) to `window[""]`.

This is why semicolons are important!

It *is* valid to set a blank string as a property of an object.  But, since it's not a valid identifier (a blank string), you can't access it without doing `window[""]`.

```
window[""] = function() {
    console.log("foo");
};

window[""](); // logs "foo"
```

Comment: Ha, nice catch! #reasonswhystrictmodeisimportant

Comment: That's why semicolons are your friends :-)

Comment: Or rather why automatic semicolon insertion is not. D: *Another one bites the dust...*

Comment: Actually, it's *not* inserting a semicolon here ;)

Comment: That's the issue... :P If I didn't rely on it, I'd be OK.